# C++ typedef function in argument

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a function, that declared next way:

```
func(int n,double *xk, double (*f)(int x));
```

I want to assign that into one word like `typedef int (*func_t)(int, *double, ...);`. I know how to assign function, but do not understand how to describe function in arguments.

Comment: This might be a hint that things are getting too complicated... You should first create a typedef for the fptr parameter, otherwise things are getting really ugly and unintuitive.

Comment: In one line it looks nice too, I think.

Comment: only if you are training for the ioccc

Comment: In my project function everywhere declared in one line (It is not in my pieces of code). If I will declare it another way, this will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef int (*func)(int, double*, double (*)(int));`

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
typedef double (*FuncPtr)(int x);  
int func(int n,double *xk, FuncPtr f);

typedef int (*func_t)(int,double*,FuncPtr);
```

One step at a time to reduce unnecessary confusion and clutter.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the function declaration looks like:

```
int func(int n, double *xk, double (*f)(int x)) {

    // ...
}
```

then the typedef of a pointer to this function would look like:

```
typedef int (*funcPointer)(int, double *, int, int, double (*)(int));
```

// usage:

```
funcPointer ptrName = func;
```

assuming you want to give this ptrName to a function called doThis():

```
int doThis (funcPointer ptrName) {
  return 0;
}
```

then you can just call it using:

```
int y = doThis(ptrName);
```

Best of luck ! =)